# Can an Aura which was not cast be attached to a permanent with shroud?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If an Aura is placed on the battlefield using [Genesis Wave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=207882) or an ability like [Sun Titan's](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=241833), can it enchant a creature that has shroud (or an opponent-controlled creature with hexproof)?

I'm looking at these rules specifically:

> 303.4a An Aura spell requires a target, which is restricted by its enchant ability.
>
> 303.4f If an Aura is entering the battlefield under a player’s control by any means other than by
>      resolving as an Aura spell, and the effect putting it onto the battlefield doesn’t specify the object
>      or player the Aura will enchant, that player chooses what it will enchant as the Aura enters the
>      battlefield. The player must choose a legal object or player according to the Aura’s enchant
>      ability and any other applicable effects.
>
> 702.17a Shroud is a static ability. “Shroud” means “This permanent or player can’t be the target of
>      spells or abilities.”

Comment: This question/answer was very confusing until I realized you wered *casting* the Aura.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they may. The cards you mentioned returned those Auras to the battlefield, so only 303.4 applies here. It should also be notes that the aura must enchant a legal object (i.e. Auras with "enchant player" must enchant players, auras with "enchant a creature you control" cannot enchant noncreatures and cannot enchant opponents creatures, etc)

Aura spells (i.e. Cards cast from your hand, and added to the stack), do require a target. It is unfortunate that they are the only spells that target, without "target" within the rules text.

Comment: Note the full text, though: "legal object or player according to the Aura’s enchant ability **and any other applicable effects**". So I can't, for instance, return Dead Weight to the battlefield enchanting Mirran Crusader even though it doesn't "target".

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they certainly can.  In fact this is a famous counterintuitive loophole (or we can be polite and call it a "quirk") remaining in the tidied-up modern rules.

**ETA**: Initially I thought an Aura might even be able to come into play attached to a creature with Protection from that Aura's colour (before falling off again as a state-based effect).  This is not in fact true: protection represents a complete inability to be enchanted by Auras of the stated quality.  So the lesson here is, if you want to make sure your hexproof/shroud creatures really can't be sneakily enchanted by  Auras, give them protection from as many of your opponent's colours as possible too.  The belt-and-braces approach!

Here's a fun question for you in return: if Genesis Wave puts Fist of Ironwood onto the battlefield when it has no creatures to enchant, do you get to put two 1/1 Saprolings into play?  Actually I'm going to have to go and ask this question immediately because I'm not 100% sure of the answer :)

Comment: I don't think protection allows you to attach it at all: "The player must choose a legal object or player according to the Aura’s enchant ability and any other applicable effects."

Comment: I thought that too, but if so then explain 702.15c: A permanent or player with protection can't be enchanted by Auras that have the stated quality. **Such Auras attached to the permanent or player with protection will be put into their owners' graveyards as a state-based action.** (See rule 704, "State-Based Actions.") ?

Comment: I believe that's the "[Faith's Shield](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262696) = enchantment removal" clause.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense!  I'll reconsider and edit my answer as appropriate :)