# Copying an Aura with Mirage Mirror

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I know the rules for [what happens when an aura that wasn't cast enters the battlefield](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/38765/what-happens-to-auras-that-come-back-from-exile) - that aura's controller chooses something to enchant with it, and this doesn't target that something.

However, I'm confused as to what would happen if I had, for instance, a [Market Festival](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarket%20Festival%5d) enchanting my Forest, and then copied that Market Festival with my [Mirage Mirror](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirage%20Mirror%5d).

My first thought is that it would instantly fizzle with nothing to enchant since it's not entering the battlefield, and whatever a permanent is enchanting is not a copiable value of an object. Or, am I wrong in that I *would* get to pick a different land and enchant that with the Mirage Mirror copy? Some clarity would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Your [Mirage Mirror](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirage%20Mirror%5d) will go to your graveyard.**

This is covered in the rulings on Mirage Mirror's Gatherer page:

> If Mirage Mirror becomes a copy of an Aura, it’s put into its owner’s graveyard unless it’s somehow attached to an appropriate object or player already. If it becomes a copy of an Equipment and is attached to a creature, it’ll become unattached when it becomes a non-Equipment artifact again.

Which is a natural consequence of the following rule (emphasis mine):

> **704.5m:** If an Aura is attached to an illegal object or player, or **is not attached to an object** or player, that **Aura is put into its owner’s graveyard**.

In order for the Mirage Mirror to not be moved to the graveyard you would first need to attach it to the land some other way. If you can find a way to attach Mirage Mirror to the land first, and then copy the [Market Festival](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarket%20Festival%5d), the Mirage Mirror will stay attached and not go to your graveyard.

Comment: Recommend referencing 303.4, and explaining why it doesn't apply, since the Question is making inferences from this rule.